# DateFormat Parsing Error

Tags: java, datetime

I have a date coming in. So for example 02/16/2012. What I need to do in order to work with my database format is convert it to 2012-02-16. I figured this would be pretty straightforward. But I can't work it. Here is my date parser.

```
String endDateString = "02/16/2012"
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"); 
endDate = dateFormat.parse(endDateString)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse it FROM one correct format, then convert TO string with another correct format. What are you doing -- is trying to interpret date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format with `yyyy-MM-dd` format, i.e. incorrect.

**SAMPLE**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat destinationFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String sourceDateString = "02/16/2012";
    String destinationDateString;

    Date dat; // this object stores "perfect" date object

    // interpreting string with input format and converting it to date
    dat = sourceFormat.parse(sourceDateString);

    // expressing date object as string in destination format
    destinationDateString = destinationFormat.format(dat);

    System.out.format("Done from %s to %s\n", sourceDateString, destinationDateString));


}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is parse the incoming format to a `Date` object

```
final SimpleDateFormat idf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
final Date indate = idf.parse("02/16/2012");
```

then reformat the `Date` object to the format you desire

```
final SimpleDateFormat odf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final String s = odf.format(indate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The date-format you specify has to match the date-format of your input like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet can tell you how to get it done.

```
SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String endDateString = "02/16/2012";
String endDate =     outputDateFormat.format(inputDateFormat.parse(endDateString));
```

Reference: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert a date at the database level. For example MySQL has a function STR_TO_DATE. In your case it would be STR_TO_DATE('02/16/2012','%m/%d/%Y')

Answer (score -1):

You are parsing with wrong format

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```